# How do I get my login code to recognise the hash passsword and log me in?

Tags: php, html, hash, authentication, passwords

I am hashing the password in the register page, however when I log in with that information it does not recognise the hash password. Therefore I just get an alert 'Incorrect information entered' If anyone can help me fix this issue that would be great.

```
<?php     
   session_start();

   if (isset($_POST["login"])) 
   {
      $formUser=$_POST["email"];
      $formPass=$_POST["password"];
      //$formPass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

      include("dbConnect.php");
      $dbQuery=$db->prepare("select * from customer where email=:formUser"); 
      $dbParams = array('formUser'=>$formUser);
      $dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
      $dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if (password_verify($formPass, $dbRow["password"])) {       

            $_SESSION["currentUser"]=$formUser;
            $_SESSION["currentUserID"]=$dbRow["id"];
            $_SESSION["currentUserName"]=$dbRow["forename"];
            $_SESSION["last_login"]=$dbRow["last_login"];

            if($formUser=="admin@gmail.com")
            {
                header("location: adminMembership.php");    
            }
            else header("Location: myProfile.php");
            }         
         else {
             $message1 = "Incorrect information entered";
             echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message1');</script>";
              }
   }  
?>
```

Comment: how long is the database field 'password'? Is it a varchar, char? How do you store the password?

Comment: 100 and I changed it to text

Comment: when you echo `$dbRow["password"]`, do you get a reasonable output?

Comment: Its bringing back the hashed password saved

Comment: do you have the `password_hash()` source code? i think your pass or algo is incorrect

Comment: $hashPassword = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Comment: There seems to be one of these questions every day (search for *password_verify returns false* if you want to have a look). 99% of the time, if `password_verify` isn't working it's because the supplied password simply doesn't match the stored hash. Commonly this is down to the DB column length but you say you've already ruled that out. Your code looks fine, this is almost certainly a data issue, but  there isn't much more we can do except guess. Could be extra white space, could be a typo, could be a million other things.

Comment: This is in my register page